# AngularJS get path value

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, url-parameters

I  need to populate a  form  by getting the id from the URL, without using HTML5 mode.

my URL will be http://mydomain/public/keep-me-informed?id=19

I don't want to use #/?id=19  in URL.
on server side, I do certain operations by getting the id parameter and render the page. when the page loads, I need to get the id and call some service to  populate the form.

I do not have any routing. $location.search() works only with # or HTML 5 mode.

I can also have the URL  like http://mydomain/public/keep-me-informed/19

Now what would be the clean way to get the value 19 in my controller.

Comment: Please provide proper information or code sample of what you have done.

Comment: in controller : get current url with `window.location.href` and with string lastindexof('/') and substring methods get id from url

Comment: @ArjunNayak I thought this question did not require code sample. Because I had explained what I tried  and I had tried looking for solution from   many similar post with code samples, and all those failed for me, but as suggested by others, only javascript  seems to be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

You can get the id value by parameter name, which is `id`

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var id = getParameterByName('id');
```